# Apt-Get not working behind corporate firewall on Win 7 in VirtualBox with proxy set

Tags: proxy, ubuntu-12.04, virtualbox, firewall, apt-get

### The issue

I'm trying to run apt-get on Ubuntu virtual box, but I keep getting connection and time-out errors.  I'm not sure what is causing them because the proxies are set.  Here is my system:

### System config

```
HOST: Win 7 Enterprise, SP1 (64-bit OS)
RAM: 8 GB
CPU: Intel i5 2.6GHz
VirtualBox 4.2.12
Ubuntu 64 (ubuntu-12.04.2-server-amd64.iso)
```

### Steps to reproduce issue

Here is the workflow and the error that it produces:

1) SSH to the Ubuntu VM from GitBash (or any other *nix command line).  Note: The `<localhost_alias>` has already been configured in the hosts file.

```
ssh -l<username> -p<ftp_port> <localhost_alias>
```

2) Set your proxies.  I simply copy-pasted these from a text file onto the command line and hit enter to process the last one also.

```
export http_proxy=http://proxy.somecorpdom:8080/
export https_proxy=https://proxy.somecorpdom:8080/
export no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1,*.somecorpdom
```

3) Run apt-get update.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

### Results and errors

After running the update command, the following immediately displays, but hangs for several minutes:

```
0% [Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.15)] [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (91.189.92.202)]
```

Eventually the former message goes away and I get this (un-abridged):

```
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports InRelease
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex
23% [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.14)]
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted amd64 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe amd64 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse amd64 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Sources
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Sources
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Sources
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Sources
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main amd64 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe amd64 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
23% [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.14)]
```

It hangs at "23%" for quite awhile. After another several minutes this output is displayed:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/source/Sources  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/source/Sources  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/source/Sources  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/source/Sources  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I am behind a corporate firewall/proxy.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found out the answer.  Here is the fix:

add these two lines to `/etc/apt/apt.conf` as sudo

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://somecorpdom:8080/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://somecorpdom:8080/";
```

then apt-get should work in your Ubuntu.  (Change "somecorpdom" to your proxy)

Comment: It's funny, because I had to remove those lines and put an Export entry in my .bashrc instead to make it work.

Comment: Saved me after about 4 hours of confoundity.

Answer (score 3):

You can just export the proxy as you did:

```
export http_proxy=http://proxy.somecorpdom:8080/

export https_proxy=https://proxy.somecorpdom:8080/
```

And then try `sudo -E apt-get update`.

Comment: @Arman H: Thanks for the suggestion! I've long since left that job, but this info could be useful in the future. Best regards.

Comment: I only edited the formatting in Chetan's answer; if this information is useful, all credit is due to him/her.

Comment: The -E switch! I love you!